# How to fix deployment showing only the content from before repository was renamed?

Tags: git, github, deployment, web-deployment, mern

I changed my repository name on GitHub. Now when I deploy the website, it only shows the content that was there before renaming the repo.

I did run "git remote set-url origin NEW_URL" and it gets pushed correctly. I can see the new changes in the remote repo. It just doesn't show up when I deploy. Running "git remote -v" also shows the new URL. Here's the repo https://github.com/Undisclosed64/Trackr

I couldn't find a single answer to this. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Git itself is not a deployment system. Presumably you're using a real deployment system, such as maven or npm or whatever. That's likely where your problem is; what are you using and how?

Comment: @torek Yeah git is a version control system. I am using npm. The reason I thought the issue is with git is that the deployed version was all fine as expected before I renamed it.

Comment: But what is your deployment system? Maybe it's configured to fetch the latest version from your old repo name? Tell us more about *how* you deploy.

Comment: I notice this link in your repo, to a "cyclic:prod" deployment history: https://github.com/Undisclosed64/Trackr/deployments/activity_log?environment=cyclic%3Aprod , and that seems to say it's deployed from the latest commit in your repo. Is that your deployment?

Comment: @joanis Yeah Joanis, that is my deployment. I just deployed it to cyclic and it was working as expected, deploying every change I made in the repo until I renamed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minified JavaScript files in your project still contain references to "BugTracker". For example: https://github.com/Undisclosed64/Trackr/blob/main/client/build/index.html contains "Sign in to BugTracker".

It seems that you deploy straight from the repo (without a server build) so I think you just need to rebuild your project, push build artifacts, and redeploy.

Comment: Thank you!! Thank you so much!! I was absolutely clueless about the issue. You saved me. I did rebuild the build folder and now it's working.